# While training deep learning model using tensorflow library i am getting error: ResourceExhaustedError OOM on gpu(128 gb RAM) Kindly help me

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Documents\bangla-sentence-correction-master>python train.py
Sit back and relax, it will take some time to train the model...
Vocabulary size 250000
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py:417: calling reverse_sequence (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) with seq_dim is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
seq_dim is deprecated, use seq_axis instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:432: calling reverse_sequence (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) with batch_dim is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
batch_dim is deprecated, use batch_axis instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From train.py:228: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
into the labels input on backprop by default.

See @{tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2}.

epoch 1
  training Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[6656,250000] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Reshape, Variable_1/read)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

```
     [[Node: rnn/while/cond/Add/_87 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_421_rnn/while/cond/Add", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](^_clooprnn/while/cond/ArgMax/dimension/_1)]]
```

Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 321, in 
    _, l = sess.run([train_op, loss], fd)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[6656,250000] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Reshape, Variable_1/read)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

```
     [[Node: rnn/while/cond/Add/_87 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_421_rnn/while/cond/Add", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](^_clooprnn/while/cond/ArgMax/dimension/_1)]]
```

Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 218, in 
    decoder_logits_flat = tf.add(tf.matmul(decoder_outputs_flat, W), b)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 2014, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 4278, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\CVL-Acoustics\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1740, in **init**
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[6656,250000] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Reshape, Variable_1/read)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

```
     [[Node: rnn/while/cond/Add/_87 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_421_rnn/while/cond/Add", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](^_clooprnn/while/cond/ArgMax/dimension/_1)]]
```

Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

Comment: Sounds like it's running out of memory

Comment: can you please help me how to sort this problem @JammyDodger

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this would happen.

- Try reducing the parameters of the network.
- Try decreasing your batch size.
- Check if another kernel is currently active that is allocating the memory.